# Drupal/PHP - Get a specific value in an array

Tags: php

Hi
Suppose I have the code below:

```
    [taxonomy] => Array
    (
        [118] => stdClass Object
            (
                [tid] => 118
                [vid] => 4
                [name] => A
                [description] => 
                [weight] => 4
            )

        [150] => stdClass Object
            (
                [tid] => 150
                [vid] => 5
                [name] => B
                [description] => 
                [weight] => 0
            )

    )
```

How can I only get the tid number and exclude others, could someone please give me a suggestion?

Thanks you

Comment: Couldn't you use $taxonomy[x]->tid?

Comment: The array is part of a node object, right? So I added the drupal tag.

Comment: @rik Adding drupal context to the question improve things at all, this is PHP only. Plus adding tags on guesses probably isn't best practise.

Comment: is the array key always the same as the tid value? surely then you'd just need to get the array keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming taxonomy is key of array $arr, You can fetch tid as,

for example ,

```
$key = your key //the key for which you want fetch record

    $arr['taxonomy'][$key]->tid;
```

For getting all tid values,

```
$result = array();
foreach($arr['taxonomy'] as $key=>$value)
{
      $value = (array)$value;
      if(array_key_exists('tid'), $value)
     {
           $result[] = $value['tid'];
     }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: [118] will change dynamically due to different terms/node, so this solution can be improved.

Comment: @Charles: Yes, 118 will be dynamic. I just given an example. You can replace 118 with dynamic value. Let me edit answer for your reference.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation, Actually, I want to get the tid value from the array while I found the key "tid" in it?

Comment: @Charles: I have edited my answer which will give all tid values. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tids = array_keys($yourArray);
```

This works because the first level key and the values of subkey "tid" are the same.

Comment: so array_keys() return 118 and 150... But, if I want to check if the array have the key=tid then return the tid value, how to do it?

Comment: array_keys() does not inject or omit values. It returns all keys and the condition "key=tid" is true for all of them.  If you want to extract only a subset (or even only one) TID, you could do `array_intersect(array_keys($yourArray), $yourTIDs)`.

Comment: @Charles Yeung: given `array_keys` as above, just loop through the array keys (using `foreach`? or similar) and check `if($taxonomy[$key]->tid == $key)`

Answer (score 0):

Charles Yeung you're requirements aren't clear, you say in the other answer (for Nik) that the taxonomy id is dynamic, equally it seems you have more than one taxonomy node, so can I assume you just want return an array of `tid` values, right?

Equally you said to rik that you want to check if the key=value, I've no idea what you mean by that, but perhaps you could start here...

```
$tid=array();

foreach($taxonomy as $key=>$value) {
    $tid[]=$value->tid;
}

print_r($tid);
```

This will give you an array of `tid` values, if you want to put a condition in there to constrain your output then feel free to do so, problem is your explanation of your requirements aren't clear.

Comment: I am sorry for the unclear requirement, please consider this problem: How to check if an array contain key=tid, then return tid's value? Thanks you